# Google cloud compute engine high latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just started using google cloud, and I've been having issues with my instance. The connection is really unstable and has really high ping. Used speedtest to test it, and has over 150 ms. Is this normal? It shouldnt be. I'd appreciate anyones help.

Comment: Where are you?  And where is the server you are trying to ping?

Comment: Both in Europe.

Comment: Share the region/zone information of your GCE instance and the server you used for ping test.

Comment: Europe West, Belgium. I used ooklas speedtest on the server itself...